# What happens in linux when a dynamic library is updated on disk

Tags: linker, loading, dynamic-library

What happens in linux when a dynamic library is loaded, updated on disk, then a new process is started that links to that library?  Is the new process linked against the old in memory copy or the newer version on disk?

Answer (score 2):

When package managers update files on disk, they actually *delete* the old file and write a new file in its place. The result is that, old applications which had already opened the library, continue to see the old one -- the old file still exists on disk and in memory, but has *no file names* pointing to it anymore. These kinds of files are called *orphans*.

Meanwhile, applications started after the library was replaced, start using the updated version of the library.

This is why, after a power loss, you sometimes see the following messages in logs or during bootup:

```
EXT4-fs (sda3): 34 orphan inodes deleted
```

The old system was still accessing these files as it crashed, but they aren't visible to applications anymore, so they should be deleted.